# Can't localize python HTMLCalendar in django

Tags: python, django, localization, calendar

**Update:** *After researching a bit about the problem, (solved ASCII error, but now returns ValueError) I found that this is a documented bug ([issue #3067](http://bugs.python.org/issue3067)) and therefore irresolvable until the bug is fixed in Python 2.7.3*

---

I'm trying to localize a calendar made with python HTMLCalendar in django, with no results. The calendar was made with [code from Elving Uggedal](http://journal.uggedal.com/tags/calendar/) but it seems impossible to localize it.

Here is the code:

**models.py**

```
import calendar
from datetime import date
from itertools import groupby

from django.utils.html import conditional_escape as esc

class EventCalendar(calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar):

    """
    Event calendar is a basic calendar made with HTMLCalendar module.
    """

    def __init__(self, events, *args, **kwargs):
        self.events = self.group_by_day(events)
        super(EventCalendar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def formatday(self, day, weekday):
        if day != 0:
            cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
            if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
                cssclass += ' today'
            if day in self.events:
                cssclass += ' filled'
                body = ['<ul>']
                for event in self.events[day]:
                    body.append('<li>')
                    body.append('<a href="%s">' % event.get_absolute_url())
                    body.append(esc(event.title))
                    body.append('</a></li>')
                body.append('<ul>')
                return self.day_cell(cssclass, '%d %s' % (day, ''.join(body)))
            return self.day_cell(cssclass, day)
        return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')

    def formatmonth(self, year, month):
        self.year, self.month = year, month
        return super(EventCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

    def group_by_day(self, events):
        field = lambda event: event.meeting_date.day
        return dict(
            [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(events, field)]
        )

    def day_cell(self, cssclass, body):
        return '<td class="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, body)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.utils import translation

from e_cidadania.apps.spaces.models import Meeting, Space
from e_cidadania.apps.cal.models import EventCalendar

def calendar(request, space_name, year, month):

    # Avoid people writing wrong numbers or any program errors.
    if int(month) not in range(1, 13):
        return render_to_response('cal/error.html',
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    place = get_object_or_404(Space, url=space_name)
    next_month = int(month) + 1
    prev_month = int(month) - 1

    meetings = Meeting.objects.order_by('meeting_date') \
                              .filter(space = place,
                                      meeting_date__year = year,
                                      meeting_date__month = month)

    cur_lang = translation.get_language()
    print 'DEBUG:LANG: %s' % cur_lang
    cur_locale = translation.to_locale(cur_lang)+'.UTF-8' #default encoding with django
    print 'DEBUG:LOCALE: %s' % cur_locale
    cal = EventCalendar(meetings, settings.FIRST_WEEK_DAY, cur_locale).formatmonth(int(year), int(month))

    return render_to_response('cal/calendar.html',
                              {'calendar': mark_safe(cal),
                               'nextmonth': '%02d' % next_month,
                               'prevmonth': '%02d' % prev_month,
                               'get_place': place},
                               context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I've tried using LocalizeHTMLCalendar, which should return a localized HTMLCalendar, but using it as a base class it returns an ASCII decoding error in the calendar module (the files have utf-8 coding declared).

I also tried overriding the locale arrays day_name, day_abbr, month_name and month_abbr, which ended in the calendar rendering empty.

Example:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

calendar.day_name = [_('Monday'), _('Tuesday'), _('Wednesday'), _('Thursday'), _('Friday'), _('Saturday'), _('Sunday'), ]
```

I can't seem to find a way to localize this calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny, I just did this yesterday and stumbled across your question by accident.

Here's how I got past the hurdles, sorry a bit complicated:

settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE           = 'en-us'
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK       = 0     # 0 is Sunday
# Convert to calendar module, where 0 is Monday :/
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK_CAL   = (FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK - 1) % 7

# figure locale name
LOCAL_LANG              = LANGUAGE_CODE.split('-')[0]
LOCAL_COUNTRY           = LANGUAGE_CODE.split('-')[1].upper()
LOCALE_NAME             = LOCAL_LANG + '_' + LOCAL_COUNTRY + '.UTF8'
```

I think that is the answer above.  Are you using Ubuntu/Debian?  I couldn't get it to work unless the '.UTF8' was on there.  I also needed the utf8 python header below.  Continuing ...

view:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
class kCalendar(calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # some customization I did ...
        calendar.LocaleHTMLCalendar.__init__(self, *args)  
        # super didn't work, can't remember why...
# more customization here...

kcal = kCalendar(date, settings.FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK_CAL, 
    settings.LOCALE_NAME)
calhtml = kcal.formatmonth(date.year, date.month)
```

Also, I needed to install some locale "packs" since I had blown away everything with localepurge.  Here is a script for Ubuntu:

add_lang_pack.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo -e "\nUsage: `basename $0` <locale, eg: en_US>\n"
  exit 1
fi

sudo /usr/share/locales/install-language-pack $1

if grep -q "$1" /etc/locale.nopurge
then
    # code if found
    echo -e "\n** not adding $1 to /etc/locale.nopurge, is already there.\n"
else
    sudo sh -c "echo $1 >> /etc/locale.nopurge"
    sudo sh -c "echo $1.UTF-8 >> /etc/locale.nopurge"
fi

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice! But that code only works for one language as far as I see it. I think I can make it get the current user lang with get_current_language() since my apps is multilanguage. Anyway, thanks for the answer, I'm going to make some tests

Comment: Yes, instead of getting the locale name from settings, get it from the user profile, and pass it to the constructor.  Should work fine.

Comment: I modified the code but now it returns a ValueError "Too many values to unpack" like it's unable to manage the locale :/

Comment: I'm marking your answer as right since it solved the problem, regardless from the python bug.

Answer (score 0):

It might be completely irrelevant, but in case of no other ideas, try adding

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

as the first line of your module file.

Comment: The files already had utf-8 coding declared at the top of the file, but it doesn't seem to work